# Convertir json en angular

Tags: javascript, array

Soy nuevo en angular y usando `amchart`.

Realizo una llamada a un api la cual me devuelve el siguiente objeto:

```
[{
fecha: "2021-08-01T18:00:00-06:00",
nombre: "EspaciodisponibleC:",
valor: 69
},{
fecha: "2021-08-01T18:00:00-06:00",
nombre: "EspaciodisponibleD:",
valor: 0
},{
fecha: "2021-08-01T18:00:00-06:00",
nombre: "EspaciodisponibleE:",
valor: 0
}]
```

Es posible poder convertir este objeto y obtener el siguiente resultado

```
[{
fecha: "2021-08-01T18:00:00-06:00",
EspaciodisponibleC:69,
}, {
fecha: "2021-08-01T18:00:00-06:00",
EspaciodisponibleD: 0,
}, {
fecha: "2021-08-01T18:00:00-06:00",
EspaciodisponibleE: 0,
}]
```

Lo que necesito es crear una llave nueva con el valor de la llave "`nombre`" y a esta asignarle el valor de la llave "`valor`".

Espero me haya explicado bien

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo que preguntas de asignar una llave con el valor de otra es posible pero los objetos de entrada y salida no tienen un formato válido: `... { 1: fecha: ...`. Esos "índices" que tiene el ejemplo en cada elemento no se pueden interpretar.

Comment: no entiendo lo que dices, este seria el formato, acabo de añadir una imagen para que quede mas claro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes lograrlo usando, por ejemplo, [array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

#### Ejemplo:

```js
let data = [{
  fecha: "2021-08-01T18:00:00-06:00", nombre: "EspaciodisponibleC:", valor: 69
}, {
  fecha: "2021-08-01T18:00:00-06:00", nombre: "EspaciodisponibleD:", valor: 0
}, {
  fecha: "2021-08-01T18:00:00-06:00", nombre: "EspaciodisponibleE:", valor: 0
}];

let info = data.map(d => {
  return {
    fecha: d.fecha,
    [d.nombre]: d.valor
  };
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(info));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Marcos me funciono a la perfección